# if $ A^2 = 2I $, then $ A + I, A - I $ are invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Let $ A $ be a matrix of order $ n \times n $ and assume $ A^2 = 2I $. I want to prove than $ A + I $ and $ A - I $ are invertible. Is my proof valid?

$ A^2 = 2I \Rightarrow A^2 - I = I => (A - I)(A + I) = I $

Therefore, $ A - I, A + I  $ are invertible

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: You can as well notice that $\pm 1$ are not the eigenvalues of $A.$ This method can be applied to invertibility of $A-\lambda I,$ provided that $p(A)=0,$ $p(\lambda)\neq 0,$ for a polynomial $p(x).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc do you want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial such that $p(A)=0.$ If $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible, then $Av=\lambda v$ for a nonzero vector $v.$ Then $0=p(A)v=p(\lambda)v,$ hence $p(\lambda)=0.$ Therefore for any $\lambda$ such that $p(\lambda)\neq 0$ the operator $A-\lambda I$ is invertible.

In the OP case $p(z)=z^2-2.$ The  roots are $\pm \sqrt{2}.$ Therefore $A\pm I$ are invertible.